# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:in python . I have checked the access also

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

While running below code in python a PermissionError is raised. I have checked the access for that folder but I am not able to download the file from google drive.

```
import requests

def download_file_from_google_drive(id, destination):
    URL = "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download"

    session = requests.Session()

    response = session.get(URL, params = { 'id' : id }, stream = True)
    token = get_confirm_token(response)

    if token:
        params = { 'id' : id, 'confirm' : token }
        response = session.get(URL, params = params, stream = True)

    save_response_content(response, destination)    

def get_confirm_token(response):
    for key, value in response.cookies.items():
        if key.startswith('download_warning'):
            return value

    return None

def save_response_content(response, destination):
    CHUNK_SIZE = 32768

    with open(destination, "wb") as f:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(CHUNK_SIZE):
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_id = '0Bw1MN_HtMQh4V0pVRm8tX3o4VDlIUXQ5TjltN1d3cWRFOFU0'
    destination = r"D:\Data\Reshma"
    download_file_from_google_drive(file_id, destination)
```